# How to Properly Declare Array of Custom Objects in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, class, swift, instantiation

Here is my custom class...not sure if I'm missing anything in it...

```
import UIKit

class baseMakeUp {
    var Image = UIImage()
    var Brand: String
    var Color: String
    var Rating: Int = 0

    init (Brand: String, Color: String) {
        self.Brand = Brand
        self.Color = Color
    }
}
```

I'm trying to instantiate here...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let cellIdentifier = "cellIdentifier"

    var foundation: [[baseMakeUp]]
    var blush: [[baseMakeUp]]
    var eyes: [[baseMakeUp]]
    var lips: [[baseMakeUp]]
    var nails: [[baseMakeUp]]

    // put some test data in makeup arrays here...
    foundation[0].Brand = "Revlon"     -------------> "Expected declaration" error.
    foundation[0].Color = "Red"
    foundation[0].Rating = 3
    foundation[1].Brand = "MAC"
    foundation[1].Color = "Blue"
    foundation[1].Rating = 4
```

I didn't include the rest of the ViewController class, because I didn't think it was necessary.

The error occurs when I attempt to assign a value to foundation[0].Brand

Appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: Thank you all for your help. To clarify, I wasn't trying to use 2D arrays, so I've fixed that. However even after I've created a new object of BaseMakeUp type, when I try to append it, I still get "expected declaration" error. I believe the error is indeed with my declaration of the array because when I try to type foundation again, Xcode doesn't autocomplete or change the word color as usual. Not sure what's missing.

Answer (score 49):

First, I'm going to assume you didn't want 2d arrays. If you did, I'll answer your question from that perspective below.

```
    var foundation = [baseMakeUp]()
```

Creates an empty array of baseMakeUp called foundation. You can't use subscripting to add elements to an array, you can only use it to change existing elements. Since your array is empty you add elements with append.

```
   foundation.append(baseMakeUp(Brand: "Brand", Color: "Color"))
```

Since you don't have a baseMakeUp initializer that allows you to pass a rating that element's rating is 0. However since you appended it to your array you can now use subscripting to change it's Rating variable like this:

```
foundation[0].Rating = 3
```

**If you did intend for 2d arrays.**

```
    var foundation = [[baseMakeUp]]()
```

To create the array

```
    foundation.append([])
    foundation[0].append(baseMakeUp(Brand: "Brand", Color: "Color"))
    foundation[0][0].Rating = 3
```

The first line appends an empty array to your top level array. The second line appends a  baseMakeUp to the array added in the first line. The third line uses subscripting to change the Rating of the first element in the first array of your 2d array.

Hopefully that helps with your problem.

**Additionally**

I was going to add points 1 and 2 from jday001s answer here, but you should check out their answer as well.

**Edit**

I just realized that you're trying to add elements to your arrays in the wrong scope.

You'll have to move your

```
foundation.append(baseMakeUp(Brand: "Brand", Color: "Color")
```

inside a function and call it yourself or place them inside something like viewDidLoad

eg:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var foundation = [baseMakeUp]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        foundation.append(baseMakeUp(Brand: "Brand", Color: "Color")
        foundation[0].Rating = 3
    }
}
```

Hopefully that's helpful.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope I'm being clear enough.

Comment: Yes that was it the whole time, I was in the wrong scope trying many things! Thanks again for your help, I hope to pass it on!

Comment: But when I need to access the foundation array now, it would result like - BaseMakeup(Brand: "Something", color:"Something"). How do I get it as a simple result like {Brand: "SOmething", color: "Something"}?

Answer (score 9):

You have a few things going on here:

1. You are missing some naming conventions. Class names should be capitalized (`baseMakeUp` should be `BaseMakeUp`).
2. Class vars should be lower case (`image`, `brand`, `color`, `rating`). Also `brand` & `color` in the init method.
3. Do you intend for your `foundation` array to be multidimensional? If you just want a regular array, I'd go with something like:

   ```
   var foundation = [BaseMakeup]?
   ```
4. As the other answer says, you also need to instantiate BaseMakeup objects using your init method:

   ```
   let aBaseMakeup = BaseMakeup(brand: "Revlon", color: "Red")
   ```
5. After that, you can add BaseMakeup objects to your array like this:

   ```
   foundation?.append(aBaseMakeup)
   ```

Hopefully I'm understanding what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

First Create a custom class...

```
import Foundation

class ClassName{

  var id: Int?
  var name: String?
  var category_name: String?
  var price: Double?

   init(json: JSON) {
        self.id = json["id"].int
        self.name = json["name"].string
        self.category_name = json["category_name"].string
        self.price = json["price"].double
}

}
```

Use can  use this Class in viewcontroller by following lines

```
var arrayName:Array<yourclassname> = Array()
print("/(yourclaseename[0].name)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your class object

example:

```
var foundation = baseMakeUp(Brand: "Some Brand", Color: "Red")
```